# C# SerialPort class

Tags: c#, serial-port

We see strange behavior with the .NET SerialPort.
We don't get the correct configuration from ports as they are configured in Windows.

For example, com1 is configured in windows at a baudrate of 38400
In code:

```
     SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
```

serialPort.BaudRate is always 9600.

When we use the GetDefaultCommConfig winApi from kernel32.dll we get the correct baudrate.

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: you know you can change `serialPort.BaudRate` to meet your connection demands?

Comment: Because it uses [default baud rate](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/io/ports/SerialPort.cs,ddd702bcbeb64b19) when you creating an instance with one parameter.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.baudrate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_BaudRate

Comment: You could also use this constructor : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort__ctor_System_String_System_Int32_

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know serialPort.BaudRate but you can do an easy test.
Check via de Device Manager of Windows you COM ports and for an existing one, set the baudrate at 38400 (Just an example)

Suppose it is COM3.
Then create in C# a new SerialPort object via 
      SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");

Then check it's BaudRate. It is not 38400. So under the hood, the COM3 in C# isn't the COM3 with the same parameters as configured in Windows.